# Bootstrap model messing up formatting when closed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Website: http://zarwanhashem.com/index2

I am not strong with HTML and CSS. I am using a website template for my personal website and I added a model personally that comes up when you click the first project in the Projects section.

When you close the model this blue outline comes around the image, and I don't know how to get rid of it: http://gyazo.com/c0aaa44f903069cb456041ed883d4ab8.png
The outline goes away when I open/maximize another application but comes back once I minimize it.

The projects section:

```
<!-- Portfolio Section -->
<section id="portfolio" class="cbp-so-section cbp-so-init">
    <div class="container cbp-so-side cbp-so-side-top">
        <h1>My Projects</h1>

        <ul id="portfolio-grid" class="row portfolio-row">
            <li class="portfolio-mix col-md-4 ui-design">
                <figure class="portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/AIrobot.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="caption-bg"></div>
                        <h3>AI Fighter Robot - Java</h3>
                        <p class="portfolio-item-description">This object oriented robot fought            robots created by other students in a third party environment.
                                                              Multiple robots were created in order to test various...</p>
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li class="portfolio-mix col-md-4 web-design">
                <figure class="portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/spaceInvaders.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="caption-bg"></div>
                        <h3>Space Invaders - Python</h3>
                        <p class="portfolio-item-description">An alien shooting game inspired by Tomohiro Nishikado's arcade game of the same name. 
                        The game includes multiple levels with different types of enemies and...</p>
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </li>
            <li class="portfolio-mix col-md-4 add-ons">
                <figure class="portfolio-item">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="assets/snake.jpg" alt="">
                        <div class="caption-bg"></div>
                        <h3>Snake - Turing</h3>
                        <p class="portfolio-item-description">Based on the classic arcade game of the same name, Snake
                        includes multiple difficulty levels, secret cheat codes, and... </p>
                    </a>
                </figure>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
            <div style="padding-top:80px" class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">AI Fighter Robot</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    An object oriented robot programmed in Java. It fought robots created by other students in an environment 
                    created by a third party. I also created other robots with different strategies and tested them against each 
                    other to determine the best approach. The robot included an offensive and defensive mode, and would switch 
                    between the two depending on the outcome of various calculations. Within each mode there were multiple levels 
                    of calculations to determine the best course of action for the robot to take.
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
</section>
<!-- End of Portfolio Section -->
```

Let me know if there's any other code you need (I am not sure what is required). You can access it all from the website as well. Don't go to /index, go to /index2.

Comment: Does it go away if you add border=0 to the image?

Comment: Zar, you will have to try to fix the problem yourself and do research on your own and then tell us what you tried. We are here to help not provide free web development services.

Comment: JosephU. that eliminates the red border highlighting effect. @Qambar, I have been having problems with the model for the past couple hours and I was able to fix most of them by looking at past questions but I don't know how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just have a border showing up because the image is a link.

Try adding 'outline: none' to the CSS for the anchor tag that surrounds the image.

See http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/remove-dotted-link-borders/